# Create a code in python to get the most frequent tag and value pair from a list

Tags: python, nlp, training-data, pos-tagger

I have a .txt file with 3 columns: word position, word and tag (NN, VB, JJ, etc.).

Example of txt file:

```
1   i   PRP

2   want    VBP

3   to  TO

4   go  VB
```

I want to find the frequency of the word and tag as a pair in the list in order to find the most frequently assigned tag to a word. 
Example of Results:
3 (food, NN), 2 (Brave, ADJ)

My idea is to start by opening the file from the folder, read the file line by line and split, set a counter using dictionary and print with the most common to uncommon in descending order.

My code is extremely rough (I'm almost embarrassed to post it):

```
file=open("/Users/Desktop/Folder1/trained.txt")
wordcount={}
for word in file.read().split():
    from collections import Counter
    c = Counter()
    for d in dicts.values():
        c += Counter(d)

print(c.most_common())

file.close()
```

Obviously, i'm getting no results. Anything will help. Thanks.

UPDATE:

so i got this code posted on here which worked, but my results are kinda funky. here's the code (the author removed it so i don't know who to credit):

```
file=open("/Users/Desktop/Folder1/trained.txt").read().split('\n')

d = {}
for i in file:
    if i[1:] in d.keys():
        d[i[1:]] += 1
    else:
        d[i[1:]] = 1

print (sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True))
```

here are my results:

```
[('', 15866), ('\t.\t.', 9479), ('\ti\tPRP', 7234), ('\tto\tTO', 4329), ('\tlike\tVB', 2533), ('\tabout\tIN', 2518), ('\tthe\tDT', 2389), ('\tfood\tNN', 2092), ('\ta\tDT', 2053), ('\tme\tPRP', 1870), ('\twant\tVBP', 1713), ('\twould\tMD', 1507), ('0\t.\t.', 1427), ('\teat\tVB', 1390), ('\trestaurant\tNN', 1371), ('\tuh\tUH', 1356), ('1\t.\t.', 1265), ('\ton\tIN', 1237), ("\t'd\tMD", 1221), ('\tyou\tPRP', 1145), ('\thave\tVB', 1127), ('\tis\tVBZ', 1098), ('\ttell\tVB', 1030), ('\tfor\tIN', 987), ('\tdollars\tNNS', 959), ('\tdo\tVBP', 956), ('\tgo\tVB', 931), ('2\t.\t.', 912), ('\trestaurants\tNNS', 899),
```

there seem to be a mix of good results with words and other results with space or random numbers, anyone know a way to remove what aren't real words? also, i know \t is supposed to signify a tab, is there a way to remove that as well? you guys really helped a lot

Comment: Axenow removed lines of code after you edited them in. Is that correct?

Comment: it was a correction, i got this edit:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a separate `collections.Counter` for each word. This code uses  `defaultdict` to create a dictionary of counters, without checking every word to see if it is known.

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

counts = defaultdict(Counter)
for row in file:           # read one line into `row`
    if not row.strip():
        continue           # ignore empty lines
    pos, word, tag = row.split()
    counts[word.lower()][tag] += 1
```

That's it, you can now check the most common tag of any word:

```
print(counts["food"].most_common(1))
# Prints [("NN", 3)] or whatever
```

Comment: i got an error : ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 0)

Comment: Then your input is not as you show it, but has empty lines. I inserted a work-around, but it's really a separate problem that you need to fix.

Comment: hey alexis, I'm revisiting this code, the error I'm getting is for the line.strip() as undefined name line? I'm coding in spyder, shall i define line.strip()?

Comment: Oh oops, typo! `line` should be `row`. Fixed my answer.

Comment: awesome, this worked great. do you have any suggestions for printing back to a txt file with the same format? I'm using this code  with open('/Users/Desktop/output.txt','w') as file:
    for nested_list in d.keys():
        for word in nested_list:
             file.write(word + '\t')
             file.write('\n')

Comment: I don't understand how you'd use "the same format" since you now have counts to write out. Please research it a little bit and ask a new question if you can't get it to work. I don't mind if you post a comment here with a link to your new question.

Comment: yeah this is my issue, i'm trying to maintain a count for an extensions of the code: basically i'm trying to build a dictionary, use another dataset to tag the words as NN, PRP, etc. and then get the probability that a PRP comes before or after a NN or ADJ. this is my end goal, but the code you helped me with is to get a baseline. you've been super helpful, I'm going to research more

Comment: I recommend this format: `for word, d in counts.items(): for tag, num in d.items(): file.write("\t".join([word, tag, str(num)])+"\n")`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using pandas which is a great library for tabular data I would do the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("/Users/Desktop/Folder1/trained.txt", sep=" ", header=None, names=["position", "word", "tag"])
df["word_tag_counts"] = df.groupby(["word", "tag"]).transform("count")
```

Then if you only want the maximum one from each group you can do:

```
df.groupby(["word", "tag"]).max()["word_tag_counts"]
```

which should give you a table with the values you want